# sql server - join 2 tables based on earliest date in 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for query advise to gather data on the following.

**Table 1** 'Case' - contains columns: `Id, Customer, Product, Reported Date`

**Table 2** 'Activity - contains columns: `Case Id, Date Created, Created By`

There can be many activities linked to the same case.  What I'd like to do is write a query to return the following.

```
Case.Id, Case.Customer, Case.Product, Case.ReportedDate, 
Activity.DateCreated, Activity.CreatedBy,
datediff(hour, Case.ReportedDate, Activity.DateCreated)
```

BUT **ONLY** for the `activity` with the **earliest date**.  Basically showing the **time difference** between when the case was first created and the first activity was created.

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this `join`.  I tried a few things but it ended returning multiple rows per case.  Thanks very much!

Comment: What RDBMS you are using Mysql ? Sql Server ?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far and what the results were.

Comment: I'm using sql server express (2012).  Here is the query:
Select
distinct sr.SR, sr.Customer, sr.Asset, sr.DateReported, 
min(act.DateCreated) as 'Dispatched On', Datediff(hour, sr.DateReported, min(act.DateCreated)) As 'Dispatch Time (hours)', 
act.CreatedBy As 'Dispatched By', count(act.DateCreated) As Dispatches
from dbo.srs sr JOIN dbo.activities act ON (sr.SR = act.SR)
where sr.SR = '1-425789749' and sr.DateReported > '2014-01-01' and act.Note = 'Service Request Dispatched'
Group By sr.SR, sr.Customer, sr.Asset, sr.DateReported, act.CreatedBy
ORDER BY 'Dispatch Time (hours)' DESC

Comment: Results (I apologize for the formatting) -

SR Customer Asset Reported Date Dispatched On Dispatch Time (hours) Dispatched By Dispatches

1-425789749 PML CB PLATFORM - NET NEW 2014-03-04 19:53:16.000 2014-04-04 17:28:36.000 742 Emp, One 1

1-425789749 PML CB PLATFORM - NET NEW 2014-03-04 19:53:16.000 2014-04-02 13:13:41.000 690 Emp, Two 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT C.ID
      ,C.Customer
      ,C.Product
      ,C.ReportedDate
      ,DATEDIFF(HOUR, C.ReportedDate, A.DateCreated) AS [TimePassed]
      ,A.CreatedBy
FROM [Case] C INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT *,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY DateCreated ASC) AS rn
            FROM [Activity]) A 
ON C.ID = A.CaseId
WHERE A.rn = 1
```

Comment: That worked beautifully!  I love this community.  Thank you so much