# SQL join two tables on earliest date only

Tags: sql, date, join

I'm not great at SQL and having trouble understanding the other answers.

My request is similar to these two: [Join on earliest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203654/sql-join-2-tables-on-earliest-date-after-date-in-first-table) and [select earliest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505583/sql-server-join-2-tables-based-on-earliest-date-in-2nd-table).

I have the following two tables:

T1

```
user   |  lock_time   
----------------------
a | 2016-11-03 04:53:57
b | 2016-11-14 00:50:38
b | 2016-12-04 20:52:18
c | 2016-11-14 16:36:29
d | 2016-11-14 16:41:01
d | 2016-11-15 11:22:29
```

T2

```
user   |  unlock_time   
----------------------
a | 2016-11-04 05:47:51
b | 2016-11-15 13:56:28
b | 2016-12-05 23:10:51
d | 2016-11-15 13:36:29
```

I want to join these table, in such a way that each lock_time is paired to the *only* the first unlock_time, which is greater than the lock_time being joined. So the resulting example table would be:

```
user   |  lock_time   | unlock_time
-------------------------------------
a | 2016-11-03 04:53:57 | 2016-11-04 05:47:51
b | 2016-11-14 00:50:38 | 2016-11-15 13:56:28
b | 2016-12-04 20:52:18 | 2016-12-05 23:10:51
d | 2016-11-14 16:41:01 | 2016-11-15 13:36:29
```

I am here interested in the time *between* lock_time and unlock_time, so for instances where there's no possible matches between lock/unlock, that row should be dropped.

It is guaranteed there will not be multiple lock_time or unlock_time on a give *day*, but there could for instance exist two lock_time with different dates, that only match to one unlock_time. In this case I want the *first* lock_time.

Example: user A locked on 2016-11-03 and 2016-11-04, but only unlocked on 2016-11-04.

Comment: Poor table design. How to match lock/unlock?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: jarlh: These are sub tables created from logs of account status changes. The user here is that a users account can be locked/unlocked multiple times. I am interested in the time between each lock/unlock, but it only makes sense to match each lock to first possible unlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join tables by condition `l.user = u.user and l.lock_time < u.unlock_time` and get minimal `unlock_time`

```
select l.user, l.lock_time, min(u.unlock_time) as unlock_time
from
   T1 l
   JOIN T2 u on l.user = u.user and l.lock_time < u.unlock_time
group by l.user, l.lock_time;
```

**UPDATE**:
For case with `d`

T1

```
user   |  lock_time   
----------------------
d      | 2016-11-14 16:41:01
d      | 2016-11-15 11:22:29
```

T2

```
user   |  unlock_time   
----------------------
d      | 2016-11-15 13:36:29
```

and result:

```
user   |  lock_time          | unlock_time
-------------------------------------
d      | 2016-11-14 16:41:01 | 2016-11-15 13:36:29
```

you can get minimal `lock_time` after you've got minimal `unlock_time`

```
select l1.user, min(l1.lock_time) lock_time, l1.unlock_time
from (
     SELECT
        l.user,
        l.lock_time,
        min(u.unlock_time) AS unlock_time
     FROM
         T1 l
         JOIN T2 u ON l.user = u.user AND l.lock_time < u.unlock_time
     GROUP BY l.user, l.lock_time
) as l1
group by l1.user, l1.unlock_time
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple way - use a correlated sub-query to find the user's first unlock_time after lock_time:

```
select t1.user, t1.lock_time,
      (select min(t2.unlock_time) from t2
       where t2.unlock_time > t1.lock_time
         and t1.user = t2.user)
from t1
```

Comment: This query returns 'null' as `unlock_time` in case if `T1` contains a data which hasn't matched to `T2`. For example: if you insert this data: `insert into T1(user, lock_time) values ('c', '2016-12-04 20:52:18')`, query will return additional row: `|c|2016-12-04 20:52:18|null|`

Comment: @VladBochenin, I know. OP hasn't specified the expected result in that case, but I think a null makes sense here.

Comment: Sorry, if there's a lock_time, but no matching unlock_time then that row should be dropped. Rationale: I am interest in the time between lock/unlock

Comment: @Stiffo, can't you add such rows to the existing sample data? (To make the problem clearer.)

Comment: @jarlh I have added examples of what I mean now

Answer (score -1):

You have not posted full table columns details, I wrote query based on your example. It may work try it.

```
select t1.user,t1.lock_time, t2.unlock_time  from T1 t1, T2 t2 where t1.user=t2.user and t2.unlock_time >= t1.lock_time;
```

Comment: this query returns 3 rows for `b`

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because it simply joins *all* later unlocks with each lock. Moreover you are suggesting a join syntax that was made redundant in 1992.